# Breakpoints not being hit in VS 2017 xamarin android project

Tags: debugging, xamarin, mono

I am trying to create a cross platform application using visual studio community 2017. My app builds and deploys fine on my physical device.

I have made changes to the oncreate method in the MainActivity class and intend to debug the code to see the result, but the breakpoints I set within the oncreate method have never been hit. I tried to create a new cross platform project, it does the same thing. I put breakpoints in the shared pcl project, but they get hit fine.

I have looked through online and tried everything I can find:

Cleaned the solution and rebuilt;

Deleted the bin folder;

Checked the naming in the folder directory;

Reinstalled and updated visual studio 2017;

Nothing seems to be working. In the output window, I get this message "Resolved pending breakpoint at '...\test\test.Android\MainActivity.cs:74,1' to void test.Droid.MainActivity.OnStop () [0x00000]"

Any more advice please.

Many thanks. Zen

Comment: Restarted PC or not?

Comment: Yes, I did a couple of times. Do not know why exactly, but it appears to do with xamarin live player.

Comment: Check whether you have selected Debug for right config in Project config

Answer (score 0):

After reading the post from

[Xamarin Live Player does not start OnCreate in Android project, using the VS default project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49885017/xamarin-live-player-does-not-start-oncreate-in-android-project-using-the-vs-def)

and the post from

[How do I debug on a real android device using Xamarin for Visual Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25192573/how-do-i-debug-on-a-real-android-device-using-xamarin-for-visual-studio)

I disabled the Xamarin live player -> installed the usb drive on my computer-> turn on the usb debugging mode on my phone-> finally I am able to step through the oncreate method.